# Managed metadata column values show GUID in search results

Tags: managed-metadata, search-results, taxonomy, enterprise-search, guid

My problem is the same as the one described here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hu-HU/sharepoint2010general/thread/e3edd223-4fa7-4920-8efd-4898df85f0bf

Unfortunately, that post does not offer a working solution.

I've noticed different behavior in the search description when searching for different terms. Sometimes the managed metadata term will show as a string, and sometimes it will show with the ID and GUID in the description, even though both searches are displaying the same document as a hit.

I've also tried mapping the managed metadata column to a crawled property, but I could not locate the crawled properties for some of my managed metadata columns.

Anyone know how to fix this??

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Applying SP1 did the trick

Comment: We're actually on the December 2011 CU and I still see this problem. Could you share what version your environment is on?